# Laravel 5 Creating a New Record that BelongsTo 3 Other Tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 4 tables Users, Regions, Rentals, and Locations

1. Each User hasMany Rentals
2. Each Region hasMany Rentals
3. Each Location hasMany Rentals
4. Basically a Rental belongsTo all 3 tables

Region - id, name
Location - id, street_address, city, province, postal_code
Rental - id, region_id, location_id, user_id

I've set up the hasMany and belongsTo relationships between these tables and tested them in Tinker, but now I want to create and update rentals.

- The region_id is passed up through the request - **$regionId**
- The user_id is the Auth::id() - **$userId**
- The location_id is found by taking only() part of the request and doing a check of the locations table, and if it exists I grab the location_id - **$locationId**
- The remaining post data is grabbed using only() again for that data - **$rentalData**

All this works to this point, but how do you create and update rentals using the ids and data I've extracted, this almost works:

```
Location::find($locationId)->rentals()->create($rentalData);
```

But, need to get the $locationId and $userId into the mix somehow and it doesn't seem right to make them fillable.

I've been playing with it like this so far:

```
// Retrieve the chosen rental region
$regionId = Region::find($request->input('region_id'));

// Retrieve authenticated user id
$userId = Auth::id();

// Retrieve rental location data
$rentalLocationData = $request->only('street_address', 'city', 'province', 'country', 'postal_code');

// Does the location already exist? If not create and persist it to the database
$locationData = RentalLocation::firstOrCreate($rentalLocationData);
$locationId = $locationData->id;

// Create the rental...?
$rental = Location::find($locationId)->rentals()->create($rentalData);
```

**UPDATE**

So I can keep going dropped using the ORM and did this, but I'd still like to understand how Eloquent works beyond the basics I learnt watching Laracast videos so any help would be appreciated, right now I just find it really confusing:

```
// Retrieve rental location data from the request
$requestData = $request->only('street_address', 'city', 'province', 'country', 'postal_code');

// Does the location already exist? If not create and persist it to the database
$rentalLocation = RentalLocation::firstOrCreate($requestData);


// Retrieve the foreign key ids not included in request
$foreignKeyIds = [ 'user_id' => Auth::id(), 'rental_location_id' => $rentalLocation->id ];

// Retrieve request data for creating a rental, and merge with foreign key ids
$requestData = $request->only('region_id', 'stall', 'level', 'description');
$rentalData = array_merge($foreignKeyIds, $requestData);

// Insert new rental with all field attributes included
DB::table('rentals')->insert($rentalData);
```

**UPDATE**

What about this solutions?

RentalRequest checks the region_id exists, and the user will always be the Auth::user().

```
public function store(RentalRequest $request)
{
    // Retrieve the authenticated user
    $User = Auth::user();

    // Retrieve rental location data from request
    $requestData = $request->only('street_address', 'city', 'province', 'country', 'postal_code');

    // Does the location already exist? If not create and persist it to the database
    $RentalLocation = RentalLocation::firstOrCreate($requestData);

    // Retrieve the region for inserting the rental
    $Region = Region::find($request->input('region_id'));

    // Retrieve rental data from request
    $requestData = $request->only('stall', 'level', 'description');

    // Create a new rental, fill with request data, and add relationships
    $rental = new Rental;
    $rental->fill($requestData);
    $rental->owner()->associate($User);
    $rental->location()->associate($RentalLocation);

    // Persist rental to database
    $rental = $Region->rentals()->save($rental);

    // Return rental data for capture by AngularJS interceptor
    // TODO: filter rental data don't need it all returned to client
    return response()->json([
        'rental' => $rental,
        'action' => 'rental_registered',
        'message' => trans('rental.registered')
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why to make it so complex?

try this:

**Solution 1**

```
$User = User::find(Auth::id()); 
if(!$User) {
    return 'no user';
}

$Region = Region::find($request->input('region_id'));
if(!$Region) {
    return 'no region';
}

$locationData = $request->only('street_address', 'city', 'province', 'country', 'postal_code');
$Location = Location::firstOrCreate($locationData);

$rentalData = [
    'user_id' => $User->id, 
    'region_id' => $Region->id, 
    'location_id' => $Location->id
];
$Rental = Rental::firstOrCreate($rentalData);
```

**Solution 2**

```
// ->remember() for caching request to prevent many queries, for faster result use apc cache in config files, no need to use memcache when You're using 1 app server

if(!User::where('id', '=', Auth::id())->remember(1440)->exists()) {
    return 'no user';
}

if(!Region::where('id', '=', $request->input('region_id'))->remember(1440)->exists()) {
    return 'no user';
}

$locationData = $request->only('street_address', 'city', 'province', 'country', 'postal_code');
$Location = Location::firstOrCreate($locationData);

$rentalData = [
    'user_id' => $User->id, 
    'region_id' => $Region->id, 
    'location_id' => $Location->id
];
$Rental = Rental::firstOrCreate($rentalData);
```

Comment: I can see how this works, but it looks like in order to accomplish this you have to hit the DB 3 or 4 times.  Is there a more compact solution using the ORM to creating/updating these types of relationships?

Comment: We can remove User::find(), Region::find() lines in order to cut queries 2 queries, and 2 queries will remain. But You'll get security issue in future, because someone will pass invalid data. We can do it using raw query, but it will not give You much performance because You'll do 2 queries again: 1st insert to Location, 2nd creating Rental record (but in raw query).

Comment: I've made changes in code and used cache, in any case You'll have to do security checks in future, and You cannot avoid it.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean.  Take both your examples and playing with them a bit I came up with something that works.  What do you think of my last update?

Comment: I see You've made results :)  good job. so if You worry about performance use caching (remember() method in models).

Comment: I've read Your new update. Have to say that You've wisely used ORM features.

Comment: Thanks, it took a lot of experimenting with Tinker and referencing both your solutions.  I like how you capitalize your references makes for easy reading.  I had one other question if you have a chance.  When you do something like:  $Rental = Rental::with('region', 'location')->find(1); I get my rental with all its relationships eagerly loaded.  Now if I fill the just the rental fields and call save() they persist, but if I try to update the location fields the same way by $Rental->location->fill() and call save() they don't persist?  Do I need to find() the location and update it separately?

Comment: When You do ->location->fill() and then save() of course You're using object related to rental. You can do $Location = $Rental->location; $Location->fill() and save(). It's same as getting object by using find or where. But it is more performant, because it does not send query to get row object, because You've already eager loaded it.